# I can't pay with Paypal through WooCommerce

Tags: paypal, checkout, woocommerce, product

When I check out the products I wish to purchase from my store it directs me to Paypal's page and I need to log in to my paypal account in order to purchase the items. However, every time I try logging in it says "Please check your email address and password and try again" which is very concerning since it works when I log in through Paypal's website. I'm so confused and started searching for answers online and I found out I might have to use IPN or API.. all those stuff and I have no clue what is going on... please help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you've got WooCommerce set to run in test mode but you're using your live PayPal account credentials to try logging in.  That won't work.

If you are indeed set to test mode you need to create test accounts to play with at http://developer.paypal.com.

Alternatively, just set WooCommerce to run in live mode and then your live PayPal account credentials would work, although, you'll need to a live PayPal account separate from your seller account because you can't pay yourself.